# Swing Component (re)paint mechanism fails to properly draw, when requests are too fast

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent, repaint

From Java's documentation it says that the repaint mechanism of a Component is optimized and cached, so that even if it is called a lot of times, it won't clog the drawing pipeline.

It seems though that under really heavy invocation, sometimes it fails to draw the latest frames. Consider the following example:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestRepaint extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new TestRepaint());
        frame.setSize(300, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private long start;

    {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Repaint");
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int where = (int) ((now - start) / 5);
        if (where >= 200)
            g.drawString("DONE", 200, 30);
        else {
            g.drawString("Working...", where, 30);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

When mouse clicked on the window, then a "Working..." text will scroll to the right. On the last frame it is supposed to change into "DONE". It seems that (randomly) it fails to draw the last frame and the previous "Working..." text remains. If for example we force redraw the display (i.e. change window size), then "DONE" appears.

It seems that, since the repaint is requested too fast, the last repaint of the component fails to happen. So, is there any guaranteed way to do this?

Comment: 1) NEVER call `repaint()` from within a painting method -- EVER. 2) You should be overriding paintComponent, not paint. 3) You should call the super's method within your override. 4) Read the tutorials as this is explained in them.

Comment: **2&3)** changed code to reflect the proposed changes, nothing changed. **1&4)** Why? Where it says that I can't use `repaint` from inside a `paint` method? AFAIK we shouldn't use `paint` directly - `repaint` doesn't have this limitation, as is described here: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: By calling `repaint()` within paint, you are creating a completely un-controllable and klutzy animation and potentially messing with the painting chain. If you want animation, do it in a way where it can be controlled and doesn't have this potential issue.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your will to discuss this issue. I suspect that this problem could be bypassed, when using an external Thread to fire the repaint event (the animation is here just for displaying purposes). The question still remains though why there is this "potential issue", apart from the obvious one "It can't be done, period."

Comment: Every method has a specific function. A painting method is for painting only. It is NOT for scheduling the painting of a component. Swing components are designed to repaint themselves when a property of the component is changed. When you change the text, font, foreground etc. the component will repaint itself. If you change all 3 of those properties at once the 3 repaint requests are consolidated into a single paint() request by the RepaintManager. For animation you can use a Swing Timer to schedule the repainting.

Comment: To further support both Hovercraft Full Of Eels and Camickr's comments, calling `repaint` from within your `paint` method can setup a uncontrolled update process which will saturate the EDT with repaint requests, making it difficult (or time consuming) for it to process other events and which eventually run your CPU to 100%. A simple solution would be to use a Swing `Timer` to update the state of your animation and schedule a `repaint` at regular intervals (16 milliseconds for 60fps for example) or a `Thread` if you want more control over the frame rate, but this then introduces more issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer what if I want it to refresh as fast as possible and not on regular intervals?

Comment: @Panayotis Honestly, don't.  Swing uses a passive rendering engine, it's optimised to work this way, so it's not designed for a high frequency update cycle.  Swing can also reduce multiple repaint requests down into a smaller number of repaint events (which is what might be happening to you).  Instead you need to try and generate a update at a small enough interval so as to achieve your goal, but large enough to allow the EDT time to breath and process other events

Comment: This is what I suspected, but I was still a bit surprised that this couldn't be done.